# LogonUser() not authenticating user for invalid domain when computer is not on a domain

Tags: c++, winapi, testing, authentication

I'm having some problems with the LogonUser() API function in C++.  The computer I'm testing this on is not on a domain.  The account I'm testing with exists on the computer, but when i supply an invalid domain, it authenticates the login.

This does not seem right to me.

```
HANDLE token;

if (!LogonUser("LocalUser", "InvalidDomain", "Password",
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token))
{
    unsigned long error = GetLastError();
}
```

Is this the right behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that workgroup members don't support domain logons so the domain parameter is ignored.  This explains what you are seeing.

You can confirm this.  Try to authenticate using a real domain user (ensuring there isn't a local account with the same name).  The logon should fail.

There is an exception.  If you use the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` flag (which amends the existing logon rather than creating a new one) then a domain logon will always succeed because it isn't authenticated until you attempt to access a remote resource.

Comment: I do not think so.  `loginrc = LogonUser(L"jhadmin", L"leohp", L"jhadmin", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);` user(jhadmin) is a real domain user, but domain name(leohp) is a invalid. the valid domain is leohpc. but the funtion logon success!!

Comment: @LEo The question was about a computer that is a workgroup member.  Presumably you are talking about a domain member?

Comment: yes，But the LogonUser can not check a invalid domain name when the user name(domain user) and password is right. why?Is this the right behavior?

Comment: @LEo There's a bunch of things that might be happening.  Whatever, they are only tangentially related to this question and answer.  If you ask a new question you could usefully refer to this one as a related question.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site, you should use a "." (or "", but this is not documented) as domain to only use the local database.
I believe the undocumented behaviour of "" explains your login. If it fails to identify the user in the domain, it will try to identify it locally.

I based my answer on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx