# LogonUser API doesn't work correctly with Domain from Workstation

Tags: windows, api, dns, workgroup

For test I have setup a simple domain and added some users. I have  Win10 workstation(s) NOT joined to that domain as well. I can access the DC with from the workstations with no issues by supplying a domain username and password to see file shares through Window's explorer. I can even use LDAP from vb.net to authenticate DC accounts.

I am trying to use the LOGONUSER API (all flavors tried) in an attempt to validate a domain account (local accounts validate OK) from a workstation NOT joined to that domain. Whatever flag/combo I use, it always returns false (failed logon). The only time I get a success is when use the flag NEW_CREDENTIALS but that supposedly returns a true value by default even with invalid credentials. Apparently From reading other posts related to using LogonUser API from a workstation computer to a domain controller nobody can seem to get it to work. I have even tried it on our corp. domains with no luck. However, the program I wrote (borrowed /tried code from several sources) works fine if I put it on any computer already joined to the domain, and it will even authenticate across domains that have a full trust between them. It just will not work from non-domain workstation to a domain. What needs to be done to make this work? I can't find any official documents that say it won't work, which would be great if I could find they exist. Thanks for your time..

```
  <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String,
                                      ByVal dwLogonType As LogonType, ByVal dwLogonProvider As LogonProvider, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

Enum LogonType As Integer
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3
    LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4
    LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5
    LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9
End Enum
Enum LogonProvider As Integer
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
End Enum

public sub TryLogon()   
     Dim token As New IntPtr
    Dim Username as string = "myuser",domain as string = "mydomain.local",password as string = "password"
        Dim retVal = LogonUser(Username, domain, Password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token)
        If retVal = False Then
            Dim errMsg = New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message
            MsgBox(errMsg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Logon")
        End If
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`LogonUser()` requires that the current user has the "Act as a part of the operating system" privilege. By default, it's granted to no one, not even the administrators.

EDIT: before `LogonUser`, you need to call `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` - add the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege to the current user.

EDIT: I'll have to check, but I don't think LogonUser was meant for authenticating users from untrusted authorities (e. g. domains that the current machine is not on).

Consider creating a dummy share on one of the domain machines (maybe the domain controller), and calling `WNetAddConnection2()` against it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the everyone group to the 'act as part.. user rights option' on the DC default Domain controller and Default Domain Policy. Did gpupdate and reboot.. Made no difference. Is there anywhere else I need to add it or something else I need to do? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Did you verify that your token has this right? And what is the actual error code on failure?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really understand what you mean by my token has this right. I am running the program as a local admin on the workstation with  a valid domain user account as well as the domain administrator account (I have tried both). The API returns false but the win32 errmsg is "The operation completed successfully". The token has a value of zero after the API call

Comment: I have added the required priv to code and through the secpol.msc on both the AD controller and local workstation. Still doesn't work. I have tried several different workstations at several different domains (test and corporate) . The program runs fine on a machine already joined to one of the domains; maybe the API  just doesn't work on a non-domain workstation directed at a domain controller. I tried LDAP from the workstation and it works OK. Any other ideas?

Comment: May I ask - what are you trying to accomplish in the first place? Usually, Windows does a good job of authenticating users by itself, there's no need for programs to do the same.

Comment: We have a third party HMI control app that requires user logon(s) using OS authentication from a domain controller. If the user's authenticated, the HMI app goes to a screen that lets the users control stuff. The app can't authenticate when it is installed on a workgroup machine, It uses the LogonUser API. The dev's have even sent me a c++ test program using the API just to test logon. It fails as well on a non-domain workstation. Works fine when put on a domain member. I thought I would just write a substitute 'logon program' to replace theirs; I can't get the API to work on non-AD cpu.

Comment: Continued-- I was going to tell them how to mod their code to make it work but I can't get it to work either..I have given everyone group permissions 'Act as part of OS' on both the AD and workstation. Heck, the Microsoft example code doesn't work on a non-domain member, but works fine on domain members. As stated earlier, I have tried this on several non-workstations on different domains. None work.

Comment: Why not join those machine to the domain?

Comment: This issue extends to multiple sites with different regulations outside our control. Most sites won't allow this due to internal policies. I wish it was that easy. I wish I could just get it to work. The few sites we have domain joined members works fine. It's the other 80% that are not working. If I can prove that the API is broken or not intended to be used on non-domain computers that need to authenticate to a domain controller I can get the third party dev to use another method such as LDAP.  They can't make it work and I can't either but they say it's an MS AD issue, not API issue. Stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem on Windows 10 (1607) that was not connected to the domain by:
 - using "." as domain
 - LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE
 - LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT

Just to let you know.

The following post put me on track: [LogonUser() not authenticating user for invalid domain when computer is not on a domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451417/logonuser-not-authenticating-user-for-invalid-domain-when-computer-is-not-on-a)